# Scope of variables in C++

Tags: c++, arduino

for the sake of overview, I wanted to outsource a few functions in another file.
Therefore I created a corresponding cpp and h file and put the funtions in there:

```
#include <routines.h>
void splash()
{
    oled.startScreen();
    oled.clear();
    oled.drawImage(start_logo, 0, 0, 128, 8);
}
void prepareDisplay(){

  unsigned int i,k;
  unsigned char ch[5];
  
  oled.clear();
  oled.startScreen();
  
  
  oled.cursorTo(0,0);
  oled.printString( "ATTiny");
}
```

Problem is that those functions use variables (oled, start_logo) from the main file which leads to them being out of scope.
Main.cpp file:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "SSD1306_minimal.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <routines.h>


//eeprom adresses:
byte calibratedAddress = 0;

//global variables:
bool isCalibrated;

//pin definitions:
const byte led = PA5;

SSD1306_Mini oled;

const unsigned char start_logo [] PROGMEM = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 ongoing...
};

void setup(){   
  
  oled.init(0x3c);
  oled.clear();

  delay(1000);

  splash();
  delay(8000);
  
  oled.clear();      
}    

void loop() {
}
```

Is it somehow possible to "hand over" the variables to the outsourced functions and if yes, how?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you familiar with function parameters?

Comment: ... or with [`extern`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)?

Comment: start_logo is constant, put it in your header file as static.

Comment: Just add the definition of the globals as members to an object defined in the header instead and make the functions member functions. Those do have access to the members and you can create an instance in `Main.cpp` by simply declaring a variable `ObjectName myObject;` which would allow you to do `myObject.prepareDisplay();` and `myObject.splash();` assuming you make those member functions without running the risk of the variable names going "out of sync" which is a risk, if you're morifying the files and use the `extern` approach...

Comment: The op is programming a micro. I don't know how compliant the Arduino compiler is. I program the MSP430xxx at times. There I think C instead of c++.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to approach this. One easy way is to pass the needed varaible as an argument into the functions that need it.

```cpp
// Pass the values needed as arguments
void splash(byte oled, unsigned char* start_logo)
{
    oled.startScreen();
    oled.clear();
    oled.drawImage(start_logo, 0, 0, 128, 8);
}
```

Another way is to keep the functions as is and declare the variables in the new cpp file

```cpp
// extern says that this variable is not defined .cpp file
// It's defined in another file
extern SSD1306_Mini oled;

// static in this context makes this variable only visible to this .cpp file
// extern in another file can't get this
static const unsigned char start_logo[] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 // more
};

void splash()
{
    oled.startScreen();
    oled.clear();
    oled.drawImage(start_logo, 0, 0, 128, 8);
}
void prepareDisplay(){

  unsigned int i,k;
  unsigned char ch[5];
  
  oled.clear();
  oled.startScreen();
  
  
  oled.cursorTo(0,0);
  oled.printString( "ATTiny");
}
```